# how to generate an admin CRUD module in an existing symfony project

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine

I'm going nuts with this legacy project. It was developed with the Symfony PHP framework and i never worked with it before. Seems to me that the only way to do things is using the CLI tool. But the tools work generally with all the application.

The Symfony project is organized like the following:

- root directory
- apps directory
- and all other common directories in a Symphony project

The apps directory contains two more directories: "cms" and "site".

I want to build just ONE admin module, a CRUD, into the "cms" app.

The "cms" directory is the admin part of the application. Can you guys give me a hand to do this?

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you talking about Sym**f**ony the full stack framework or Sym**ph**ony the CMS (spot the difference) ?

Comment: About Symfony framework (PHP). Sorry about the TAG and the name. My mistake!!

Comment: Could you specified the version of Symfony ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

run the task for generating module..

```
php symfony generate:module cms CRUD
```

where cms is the app name and CRUD is the module name